# Retaining the current page of <rich:dataScroller when returning after postback

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

Having the next table/paginator combination working properly, does somebody know what I have to do to remain on the current page after `someAction` gets fired?

(Because, actually returns ever to the first page.) i can't make `someAction` as avoid because i will lose the navigation to the page i want to open

i use jsf2.0 and richfaces 4 thanks for your helps

Comment: what is t:datascroller? tomahawk?

Comment: tomahawk20-1.1.14

Answer (score 0):

[rich:datascroller docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_datascroller.html)

[image]

there is a property named "page" that controls the current page number of the table. You can either map it to a session scoped bean property so it doesn't get lost after page reload, or store it somewhere and restore it with your "action" if your page is not session scoped.

Comment: i already try the property page but it bring me the correct page number but with data of the firstpage i use a session scoped

Comment: i had this problem just when i migrate from jsf1.2 and richfaces 3

Comment: do you do server side scrolling or just pulling all the data then paginating?

Comment: i think justpulling all the data the paginating  i work with a <a4j:repeat > instead of dataTable it's can be that the problem cuz i found some link that tell there is probleme with a <a4j:repeat in rechfaces4   https://developer.jboss.org/thread/196163